# Confusion about Boost::Spirit auto-rule behavior

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm just getting started with Boost::Spirit and have problems understanding what is going on in the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename Iterator>
struct TestGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type>
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> tag;

    std::string convertTag(std::string& tag)
    {
        printf("Tag: %s\n", tag.c_str());

        tag = "_tag_" + tag;
        return tag;
    }

    TestGrammar()
            : TestGrammar::base_type(expr)
    {
        using qi::_1;
        using qi::as_string;

        using ascii::char_;

        using namespace qi::labels;

        // (1)
        tag %= as_string[+char_] [ ph::bind(&TestGrammar::convertTag, this, _1) ];

        // (2)
        //tag = as_string[+char_] [ _val = ph::bind(&TestGrammar::convertTag, this, _1) ];

        // (3)
        //tag = as_string[+char_] [ _val += ph::bind(&TestGrammar::convertTag, this, _1) ];

        expr = char_('!') >> tag;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using ascii::space;

    std::string str("!abc");

    std::string::const_iterator beg = str.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = str.end();

    TestGrammar<std::string::const_iterator> expr;

    std::string res;
    bool r = phrase_parse(beg, end, expr, space, res);

    if (r  &&  beg == end) {
        printf("Matched: %s\n", res.c_str());
    } else {
        printf("Didn't match!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This examples is supposed to parse tags (identifiers) with a leading '!', and spits them out in the same format, but with "_tag_" prepended to the tag (so "!abc" becomes "!_tag_abc"). It's just a minimal example to show my problem.

What I don't understand is what happens when I run this code using the auto-rule in (1). Instead of the expected output, I get "_tag_!abc", and indeed the `printf()` in `convertTag()` actually prints "!abc" for the tag. But why is that? I am passing `_1` into `convertTag()`, which I thought was supposed to be the attribute parsed by `as_string[+char_]`, so how come it includes the '!' parsed in a completely different rule?

When I use rule (2) instead (which I believed would be equivalent to (1)), I instead get "_tag_abc", which seems to have dropped the initial '!', but why?

Rule (3) does what I want, although I have no idea why.

From (2) it seems to me that overwriting _val in the `tag` rule actually overwrites the entire synthesized attribute of not only `tag`, but also of `expr`. Doesn't setting `_val` in `tag` only influence the synthesized attribute of `tag`? And why the hell is there a '!' in my `_1` in (1)?

// EDIT:

Whoops. I just realized that (2) and (3) probably makes absolutely no sense because it assigns the return value of ph::bind() (not of convertTag() itself) to `_val`, which probably does not do what I want (or does it?). Still, the question remains why (1) isn't working the way I want it to.

Comment: If you really just want to prepend stuff, consider `qi::attr("_tag_") >> tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are bound by reference. Since there's only one attribute exposed by `expr` it follows that the same attribute *must* be bound to both `char_('!')` and `tag`.  This is true, and explains all the issues.

The reason Spirit is ok with this is because the automatic attribute transformation and compatibility rules allow for sequences of parsers that expose (containers) of `T` to propagate into a single container-of-`T` attribute. This is so you can e.g. parse `qi::alpha >> +(qi::alnum | qi::char_('_'))`.

So, when you take the attribute in the semantic action, you *actually* get the value of the bound reference, which is directly `std::string res;` from main. Adding

```
    std::cout << "Address: " << &tag << "\n";
```

and

```
std::cout << "Address: " << &res << "\n";
```

Shows they are the same:

```
Address: 0x7fffd54e5d00
Tag: !abc
Address: 0x7fffd54e5d00
Matched: _tag_!abc
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c353f537cf59697)</kbd>**

### Other remarks:

Rule 3 does what you want because the presence of a semantic action PLUS the absense of operator %= assignment disables automatic attribute propagation. The upshot is that you get a different (temporary) string and the behaviour is what you intuitively expected.

Regarding the "whoops" I'm not actually sure. I think `phx::bind` works differently from `std::bind` (or the result is once more "magic" compatibility rules). Anyhow, I tend to avoid any confusion by using `boost::phoenix::function`:

```
struct convertTag_f {
    std::string operator()(std::string const& tag) const {
        return "_tag_" + tag;
    }
};
boost::phoenix::function<convertTag_f> convertTag;

TestGrammar() : TestGrammar::base_type(expr)
{
    using namespace qi::labels;

    tag  = qi::as_string[+ascii::char_] [ _val += convertTag(_1) ];
    expr = ascii::char_('!') >> tag;
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5177518a770769b)**

Comment: Added [my take](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5177518a770769b) on it